# Test SqlAlchemy session events with Flask and PyTest

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm using the SqlAlchemy `before_flush` event to validate objects before saving them in the database like so:

```
from models import db

@event.listens_for(db.session, 'before_flush')
def validateSomething(session, flush_context, instances):
    pass
```

I'd really like to test what I'm doing there. However, in my tests - I'm using pytest - a new session gets created for each test using a fixture. It is similar to this setup: http://alexmic.net/flask-sqlalchemy-pytest/ A function scoped fixture creates a transaction alongside a session and rolls back / removes them during teardown.

Since the event is registered on the (scoped) session in `models.db`, it doesn't fire for the events of the sessions used in the tests. Is there a way to fix this, so events get fired during tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of listening for the session instance, `listens_for()` allows to listen to events of all instances of a session class. So replacing `db.session` with `SignallingSession` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Replacing

`@event.listens_for(db.session, 'before_flush')`

with

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
@event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
```

fixed the issue for me